# Scope based on association field count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :portfolios
end

class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Each portfolio has a boolean field determining if it is full or empty.

How do I scope users based on the number of full and empty portfolios they have (as an active record relation)?

Example using select (returns an array):

```
User.select { |user| user.portfolios(full: true).count > 1 &&
                     user.portfolios(full: false).count == 1 }
```

Comment: Would you mind telling me the reason for downvote (so I can improve)?

Comment: How are you going to decide if the portfolio is full or empty?

Comment: any field or you are deciding it on number of fields with value?

Comment: Yes each portfolio has a boolean full, clarified it in my question now also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to select users with specified count of portfolios. i.e. select all users which has 2 portfolio. So, in this case you can use something like that:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    ...

    scope :with_protfolio_count, -> (count) { 
        where(id: Portfolio.having('count(1) = ?', count).group(:user_id).select(:user_id)) 
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Yes something similar to this, do you have an example where you base the count on a portfolio property as well? Say I want all users with more than one full portfolio and only one empty (added an example with select in the question)

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this is to make two queries and then join them in one array.